# Create a boolean column based on data in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data set and would like to do two things:

1. Set certain row values in Col A to 0 based on values in Col B
2. Create a new column with values of either 0 or 1 based on the edited values in Col A

My current approach is shown below - the issue is I occasionally get an error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "OCS_dose", value = 0) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

As the numbers that I am generating are randomly selected and on certain trials there are no rows to update in Col A based on the numbers in Col B.

Here is an example of my code that causes the error:

```
pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$OCS_status == 0,]['OCS_dose'] <- 0
```

OCS_status is either a 0 or 1 that is generated using:

```
pbo_OCS_status_low <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE,
                             size = pbo_n_IFNlow, prob=c(1-.863, 0.863))
```

Therefore on occasion, I have no 0's... In my mind R should then just not try to update anything.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Here is a more complete segment of my code:

```
  pbo_OCS_status_low <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = pbo_n_IFNlow, prob=c(1-.863, 0.863)) #on OCS = 1

  #OCS dose
  pbo_OCS_dose_low <- rtruncnorm(pbo_n_IFNlow, a=0, b=Inf, mean=12.8, sd=8.1)

  #IFN boolean flag
  pbo_IFN_low <- rep(0, pbo_n_IFNlow)

  #SLEDAI score 
  pbo_SLEDAI_low <- rtruncnorm(pbo_n_IFNlow, a=0, b=Inf, mean=11.1, sd=4.4)

  #Response criteria met for SRI score reduction
  pbo_SRI_low <- sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = pbo_n_IFNlow, prob=c(1-0.423, 0.423))


  pbo_IFNlow_data <- cbind(IFN_status=pbo_IFN_low,
                           OCS_status=pbo_OCS_status_low,
                           OCS_dose=pbo_OCS_dose_low,
                           SLEDAI=pbo_SLEDAI_low,
                           SRI_response=pbo_SRI_low)

  pbo_IFNlow_data <- data.frame(pbo_IFNlow_data)

  #set those off OCS to 0
  pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$OCS_status == 0,]['OCS_dose'] <- 0


  #stratifcation factor for OCS dosage
  pbo_IFNlow_data$OCS_lessthan10 <- "temp"
  pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$OCS_dose < 10, ]['OCS_lessthan10'] <- 1
  pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$OCS_dose >= 10, ]['OCS_lessthan10'] <- 0


  #stratification factor for SLE score
  pbo_IFNlow_data$SLE_lessthan10 <- "temp"
  pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$SLEDAI < 10, ]['SLE_lessthan10'] <- 1
  pbo_IFNlow_data[pbo_IFNlow_data$SLEDAI >= 10, ]['SLE_lessthan10'] <- 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if we can have a minimal reproducible example. If I understand your question correctly, you may want to try `ifelse` statement in R?

```
df <- data.frame(colA = seq(1, 10), colB = seq(11, 20))

# Set certain row values in Col A to 0 based on values in Col B
df$colA <- ifelse(df$colB > 15, 0, df$colB)

# Create a new column with values of either 0 
# or 1 based on the edited values in Col A
df$colC <- ifelse(df$colA == 0, 1, 0)

print(df)

##       colA colB colC
##    1    11   11    0
##    2    12   12    0
##    3    13   13    0
##    4    14   14    0
##    5    15   15    0
##    6     0   16    1
##    7     0   17    1
##    8     0   18    1
##    9     0   19    1
##    10    0   20    1
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this works! I had seen ifelse before, but didn't know I could use the second argument to be the original value.